# Save a File on a specific path

Tags: java, file, path, bufferedwriter, data-files

i have the current code:

```
    public void crearArchivo(String nombre) {
        archivo = new File(nombre.replaceAll("\\s", "") + ".txt");
        if (!archivo.exists()) {
            try {
            archivo.createNewFile();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

public void crearCarpeta(String nombreCarpeta){
    File directorio = new File(nombreCarpeta);
    directorio.mkdir();

}

public void crearArchivoDatos(String nombreArchivo, ArrayList<String>datos) {
    crearArchivo(nombreArchivo);
    try {
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(archivo));

        for (int i = 0; i < datos.size(); i++) {
            bw.write(datos.get(i));
        }
        bw.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

the first method create a file only if it doesnt exist and the second one create a folder finally the third method save the data my problem is that i want to save some files on the folder i created first how can i set a path to save those file there, also i have the problem that this little program will execute at diferent computers so the path will change for any computer

Comment: You don't need to create a file to write to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get paths of folders on any computer using `System.getProperty(...)` - for example `System.getProperty("user.home")` gives you the current user directory (from which you can get to the desktop and other folders), and `System.getProperty("user.dir")` gives you the path of the folder from which your program is executed.

Comment: I think he especially wants to always store his file to a given directory, irrespective of the computer. So make a relative path should be the response.

Comment: thank you using   System.getProperty("user.home")  help me a lot i could get the path of the user no matter the user that is using the program this way i can save all the files i want in a specific folder thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Creating or modifying files in Java can be done with the Java 8 NIO.2 methods.
Here is a link to the Oracle documentation : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html

For your question, you have to declare a relative path, so it will be independent of the computer it will be executed on, rather than an absolute path, which begin on the root of the filesystem.